# How to start compilation of Krusader?

Tags: linux, compilation, installation

My question is simple. It is probably something obvious what I am missing...

I downloaded Krusader (file manager) source, from their webpage in .tar.gz. I unpacked it and want to compile, but there is no ./configure, no make, no make install.

The install.txt file is not clear for me. There is information about required dependencies, but I don't know **how to start compilation?** It is probably too obvious to even note in install instruction :)

I have installed and compiled sources in past (there were ./configure, make, make install  ones). With example of Krusader I would also learn how to compile other sources of this kind

I have Linux Mint 18. I need Krusader 2.6 (newest stable). Here is link to download:
[link to download Krusader](https://krusader.org/get-krusader/index.html)

Please give me some hint, which file to launch, and how to do it. The rest I will manage on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build instructions are in the INSTALL file.  Krusader uses cmake to generate a makefile.  You can follow the instructions in the *"--- Some CMake options. Cmake execution"* section of the INSTALL file and then build using the generated makefile as per the *" --- Compilation and installation"* section.

Comment: Thank you very much Mike. i didn't know about cmake. Not even what it is. Thank you once again